# Could not find a part of the path 'xxx\xxx.xlsx'

Tags: c#, openxml

I have a MVC application which utilized Open XML to upload excel files. Everything works fine on my local machine, but as soon as I deploy it it doesn't seem to work and throws the above exception. I have given permissions to the folder for user running in IIS, which is a AD account I created. But still throws the exception. I have seen some posts about this but I am having no luck. Please see my code below and maybe advice on any changes.

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string sSheetName)
        {
            string sid = HttpContext.Session.SessionID;

            List<CleanSupplierClaim> supplierClaimsData = new List<CleanSupplierClaim>();

            try
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = file.FileName;
                    var targetFolder = Server.MapPath("~/upload/");
                    string targetPath = Path.Combine(targetFolder, fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(targetPath);
```

Comment: Is "Enable parent paths" in IIS turned on?

Comment: Also, try and log what the path on the server is actually been made of.... Given that the server/your local machine paths aren't completely identical, you might have issues there...

Comment: That did the trick, now I am getting another exception.  Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\xxx.xlsx'. This is when I try and browse the hosted site on my local machine, on the server it works fine. I have added permission for IIS user running in the app pool but still no luck,please assist.

Comment: Store the base URL in a configuration, and then append the folder structure from the root folder onwards. So you would store http://www.yoursite.com as a configuration, and then append your folder configuration after.... That would make your file accessible.

Comment: Added as answer. You should work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your web.config for running your application under the AD account.

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\user" password="password" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these troubleshooting items for you... They should get you going...

- Make sure "Enable parent paths" in IIS turned on
- Try and log what the path on the server is actually been made of.... Given that the server/your local machine paths aren't completely identical, you might have issues there...
- Store the base URL in a configuration, and then append the folder structure from the root folder onwards. So you would store yoursite.com as a configuration, and then append your folder configuration after.... That would make your file accessible.